# How to supply current url in Facebook share link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-4, facebook-sharer

I'm trying to make a Share on Facebook link with the following code:

```
<%= link_to 'Share on Facebook', 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?
  app_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&href=#{request.original_url}&redirect_uri=#{request.original_url}' %>
```

Needless to say the href and uri links don't get supplied. How can I insert the rails term `request.original_url` into this link?

Is it possible?

Comment: Use double quotes (`"`) for string interpolation (`"#{...}"`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code into :

```
<%= link_to 'Share on Facebook', "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?
  app_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&href=#{request.original_url}&redirect_uri=#{request.original_url}" %>
```